# Generic type as parameter which must implement a specific interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I've got a method which I want to recreate more generic.

```
public Task<bool> DoSomething<T>(T t) where T : Type, IAnyInterface
```

As you can see, I want a **Type** as parameter which must implement **IAnyInterface**

But if I call the method,

```
DoSomething(typeof(ObjectThatImplementsIAnyInterface));
```

I get an error:

> The type 'System.Type' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'DoSomething(...)' There is no implicit conversion from 'System.Type' to 'IAnyInterface'

So how can I accomplish that the method accepts that type?

Comment: sounds like an X,Y problem. why do you need the `Type` extra ? if you can get it via `typeof(T)` ?

Comment: Either omit the parameter and use `typeof` in the method body, or use `Type`, but check it at runtime. Right now you've got a weird hybrid where you want to demand someone pass a `Type` instance that passes certain constraints -- at compile time, which isn't possible. (No more than you can demand that someone pass a `string` with at least 4 characters in it, and check this at compile time (ignoring things like Code Contracts for the moment)).

Comment: I don't want to transfer an instance, else I want to create the instance inside the method **DoSomething(...)**

Comment: `where T : Type, IAnyInterface` specifies that `T` should inherit `Type` and also implement `IAnyInterface` interface. And you are calling method only with `Type` that's why you are seeing this error.

Comment: then simply omit the parameter `(T t)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> don't want to transfer an instance, else I want to create the instance inside the method DoSomething(...)

then simply omit the parameter. It seems to be useless in your case. Let the specification be done in the generic call:

```
public Task<bool> DoSomething<T>() where T : IAnyInterface
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    // Or create the entire instance:
    T newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

Call:

```
DoSomething<ObjectThatImplementsIAnyInterface>();
```

Edit: another way of creating an instance is to demand a parameterless constructor:

```
public Task<bool> DoSomething<T>() where T : IAnyInterface, new()
{
    T newInstance = new T();
}
```

[documentation of CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Activator_CreateInstance__1)

Comment: I now feel so stupid. This somehow did not come into my mind... +1

Comment: Silly me, for sure it's that simple and I did not come up with this idea :'D Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin you're welcome. glad to be of help

Comment: I dont see the point in using `Acivator` for calling the parameterless ctor, when there is a constraint for exactly that purpose

Comment: @Jamiec actually you are correct. I am going to incorporate this into my answer, thank you

Comment: Requiring the caller to provide a `Func<T>` to create instances is another option, if a parameterless constructor is too much to ask for. Whatever you do, avoid `Activator.CreateInstance`, as it's hideously inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You simply want

```
public Task<bool> DoSomething<T>(T t) where T : IAnyInterface
```

Which defines that `T` is a type which must implement `IAnyInterface`.

The above would allow you to pass an instance as a parameter and infer `T`:

```
DoSomething(new ObjectThatImplementsIAnyInterface());
```

More info on type constraints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

---

Based on your comment:

> I don't want to transfer an instance, else I want to create the instance inside the method

It sounds like you might want the `new()` constraint which allows you to create the instance inside the method (Note: You'll need a parameterless ctor):

```
public Task<bool> DoSomething<T>() where T : IAnyInterface, new()
{
    // now you can do this:
    IAnyInterface inst = new T();
}
```

Given `DoSomething<ObjectThatImplementsIAnyInterface>()` call.

You could, of course, take an approach where you can pass it in, or create it

```
public Task<bool> DoSomething<T>(T t = null) where T : class, IAnyInterface, new()
{
    // now you can do this:
    IAnyInterface inst = t ?? new T();
}
```

---

If you want to know the actual type at runtime it's simply

```
var runtimeType = typeof(T);
```

Comment: Matter of fact you can probably remove the parameter altogether. (not my dv btw)

Answer (score -1):

You are calling it wrong. You need to pass object that implements interface, not it's type:

```
DoSomething(new ObjectThatImplementsIAnyInterface());
```